# JSF SessionScoped Bean Fields become null primefaces

Tags: java

```
I Have added the code for menuController my bean is of @SessionScoped and when one of my class extends menuController and in there if I set the value of id and navigate to other page then id value becomes null.

    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    @ManagedBean(name = "menuController")
    @SessionScoped

    public class MenuController extends BasePage implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */

        private String id;


        public MenuController() {

        }

        public String getId() {
            System.out.println("MenuController id = "+id);

            return id;
        }     

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }


    }
```

Here is the code of bean that is inheriting the menuController and setting its id value.
THis bean is also @SessionScoped. The value of id which is set is been return null when we get from menuController

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "channelLeftPanel")
@SessionScoped
public class ChannelLeftPanel extends MenuController implements Serializable {


    public ChannelLeftPanel() {
    }

    public String channelEditPage(SelectEvent event) {

        this.setId(((GenericProduct) event.getObject()).getId());

        setSessionParameter("currentView", "/includes/content/channel/editChannel.xhtml");

        if (isDebugEnable)
            logger.debug("Channel ID = " + ((GenericProduct) event.getObject()).getId());
        return "mainContentArea";
    }
}
```

Below is the form from which we are making ajax call whose listner method set the ID in menuController and update the main content form which is basically the center area details

```
    <h:form id="leftPanelform">
        <p:dataTable var="channelDetail" value="#{channelLeftPanel.channelList}"
            widgetVar="cTable"
            emptyMessage="No Channels found with given criteria"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{channelLeftPanel.selectedChannel}"
            rowKey="#{channelDetail.id}"
            filteredValue="#{channelLeftPanel.filteredChannels}" styleClass="datatableLeft" style="width:100%">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('cTable').filter()"
                        style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{channelLeftPanel.channelEditPage}" update=":mainAreaContentform"/> 
            <p:column filterBy="#{channelDetail.name}" filterStyle="display:none; visibility:hidden;" style="width:80%">
                <h:outputText value="#{channelDetail.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column filterBy="#{channelDetail.id}" filterStyle="display:none; visibility:hidden;" style="width:20%">
                [<h:outputText value="#{channelDetail.id}" />]
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>




    </h:form>
```

Comment: could you include the code for one of such derived controllers and also if you debug into the constructor of the derived controller and from there to the super, does that give you any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: @WimOmbelets I have updated the code and regarding other part i did not get ur point

Comment: Could the issue also be that i am using ajax to update the part of the form

Comment: why the cast to `GenericProduct`? Could it be that it is causing the `id` to be nulled?

Comment: @WimOmbelets we are getting the id of GenericPoduct and setting it to the id of menuController and at last statement u can see i am logging the GenericProduct Id and it is displaying it in logs

Comment: Has anybody faced similar issue, any help would be appreciated